# Hadoop Error: Java heap space when using big dataset

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to run a Hadoop program over a big text dataset (~3.1Tb).

I'm obtaining this error all the time and I cannot see any log:

```
15/04/29 13:31:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 86% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:33:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 87% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:35:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:37:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 89% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:39:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:41:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 91% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:42:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1430221604005_0004_m_018721_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/04/29 13:43:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1430221604005_0004_m_018721_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/04/29 13:43:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1430221604005_0004_m_018721_2, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/04/29 13:43:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 92% reduce 3%
15/04/29 13:43:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/04/29 13:44:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430221604005_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1430221604005_0004_m_018721
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/04/29 13:44:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 40
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=1671885418232
        FILE: Number of bytes written=3434806868906
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=2421645776312
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=54123
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Killed map tasks=53
        Killed reduce tasks=13
        Launched map tasks=18098
        Launched reduce tasks=13
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=18095
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=833322750
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=179324736
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=833322750
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=44831184
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=833322750
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=44831184
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1644979108500
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=353987028864
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=4341029640
        Map output records=3718782624
        Map output bytes=1756332044946
        Map output materialized bytes=1769982618200
        Input split bytes=2694367
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=7203900023
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=10688027
        CPU time spent (ms)=391899480
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=15069669965824
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=61989010124800
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=17448162033664
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=2421643081945
```

The map process take more than 3 hours, and it is really difficult to debut it since that is the only output I can see.

I have a cluster with 10 servers each with 24Gb of ram and the configuration is:

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>computer61:8021</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1974</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>7896</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1580m</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx6320m</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

I added the line

> export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=8192

to the hadoop-env.sh file but nothing change.

I know this is an old question, but I applied the recommended solutions in like 50 post without any improvement.

When I use smaller dataset (~1Tb) for the same code it works fine.

Do you know at least how I can keep the logs to know where I'm getting the specific error?

Thanks

Update:

I have managed to see the log before it was deleted. Basically the error is:

```
2015-04-29 18:23:45,719 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 25874428(103497712); length = 339969/6553600
2015-04-29 18:23:47,110 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2015-04-29 18:23:47,676 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1956)
    at java.lang.String.trim(String.java:2865)
    at analysis.MetaDataMapper.map(MetaDataMapper.java:109)
    at analysis.MetaDataMapper.map(MetaDataMapper.java:21)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: What is your input buffer percentage ? Did you change this value from the default ?

Comment: I did not start the configuration of the cluster, but as far as I see in the configuration files I don't have any specific configuration for the buffer... then I get it has the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the buffer size might help. By default, Hadoop buffers 70% of the data from a mapper before it starts sorting, but for large datasets this can be too large. You can reduce this input buffer percentage by adding the following property to `mapred-site.xml`.

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent</name>
  <value>0.20</value>
</property>
```

I have set the value to 20%, but you may want to reduce this even further depending on your dataset and the amount of RAM available.

Answer (score 1):

Check yarn UI for logs or run following command on shell

`yarn logs -applicationId <yarn application id of your mr job>`

Comment: The problem is the log files are deleted just after the program fail and I cannot see anything... The command you told me gives me:

15/04/29 14:51:19 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at computer61.ant-net/192.168.0.93:8032
Logs not available at /tmp/logs/hadoopuser/logs/application_1430221604005_0004
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.

Comment: @user1753235 enable log aggregation in yarn-site.xml    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

Comment: the aggregation seems to be already enabled:

<property>
   <description>Whether to enable log aggregation</description>
   <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>