# FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

when i try to implement **hadoop** *mapreduce* program in python, the *mapreduce* executes fine when the size of input file is less.if i try to implement the same *mapreduce* for input files size more than ~50mb. i get the following error in *log* files.

> FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child :
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:244)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

with reference to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943659/hadoop-error-java-heap-space-when-using-big-dataset) i tried the following configuration changes in `mapred-site.xml`,

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1974</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>7896</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1580m</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx6320m</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value> -Xmx524288000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent</name>
  <value>0.20</value>
</property>
```

but after configuration changes only mapping does execute,and reducer does not start.

so, what could i modify, to implement *mapreduce* for large input files to run with out problem.

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine/cluster?

Comment: You are setting a limit of 2 GB for Map and 8 GB for Reduce. You are also setting a limit of 1.5 GB and 6GB for the JVM (for the heap). Try maybe to decrease them (JVM -Xmx should be around 70-80% of the upper limit set for mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb).

Comment: I tried decresing the value by -Xmx4320m.but ater running the map reduce it hangs at                                                                                15/12/10 15:43:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511280/hadoop-1-2-1-multinode-cluster-reducer-phase-hangs-for-wordcount-program/32551259#32551259 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165549/hadoop-wordcount-example-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-0

Comment: hi @markon, i have already checked the etc/hosts file. and it is fine as it works with small files. my problem is why it get hang only for large input file

Comment: I didn't mean to have a look only at the hosts file - if you read other answers as well, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167078/126125 I mean, other people had the same issue, maybe you can just search online ....